# Pending Intent from Broadcast Receiver to Activity - old data received

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I found similar questions, but none of the solutions helped me.
I have a broadcast receiver intercepting sms and forwarding the sms text to another activity. The other activity should display the latest received text.
But the other activity is ALWAYS displaying the first text received after the app was started for the first time. New sms-texts are not displayed.

What I tried:
Played around with the parameters of Pending Intent (unique random int and all 4 update options) - didnt help so far.

```
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, **rand.nextInt(50) + 1**, intent, **FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT**);
```

Here's the relevant code from the Broadcast Receiver, the notification which is also triggered shows the new and correct text each time.

```
    private void showNotification(Context context) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(context, DisplayMSG.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, str);
    Random rand = new Random();
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, rand.nextInt(50) + 1, intent, FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("RPT Notification")
            .setContentText(str + Integer.toString(n));
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mBuilder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
    NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mNotificationManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());

}  
}
```

And here's the part from the receiving activity:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String message = intent.getStringExtra(SmsReceiver.EXTRA_MESSAGE);
TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
textView.setText(message);
```

Let me know if you need more code. But I hope this should be sufficient, since it's basically working, it's just not transferring the new texts.

EDIT:
Thanks to CommonsWare here is the solution, I just added this method to the receiving activity:

```
@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) 
{
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    TextView textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tView);
    textView.setText(intent.getStringExtra(SmsReceiver.EXTRA_MESSAGE));
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> And here's the part from the receiving activity

If the activity is already running, that is the wrong `Intent`. Override `onNewIntent()` and use the `Intent` that is passed in to it. `getIntent()` always returns the `Intent` used to create the activity, not any subsequent ones that brought an existing instance back to the foreground.